# Automate filling HTML pop up forms in python

Tags: python, html, popup

I am looking for resources or guide so that I could build a Python code to fill my ~2k online forms automatically. Sorry I dont have any script to share as many resources in which python code is written to go to form URL and fill it. Since in my case it is a pop up form it doesnt really have a real URL.

Please be kind, I am new to Python.

Is there a way to do something to imitate clicks on browser window and fill in new values in the form ?

Comment: You should use [selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/). This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676036/python-webdriver-to-handle-pop-up-browser-windows-which-is-not-an-alert) might also get you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can imitate clicks in the browser using selenium https://realpython.com/modern-web-automation-with-python-and-selenium/. There are plenty of tutorials how to do that.

Other tools would be:

- https://www.cypress.io/
- http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/
- If you don't want to write code - an
  extension in the browser: https://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/