# How to set day value; using Selenum-Chrome-Webdriver in Excel-VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to leverage Selenium to automate standardized web inputs; however, the remaining piece is handling the calendar popup. I am needing to dynamically set the values of the calendar to the relative cell value in the sheet.

I am using my windows computer- Excel-VBA; using Selenium Webdriver and Chromedriver. I've tried using both Xpaths-Method, ExecuteScript (JS), and controlling mouse.

```
Sub googStart()

Dim bot As New WebDriver
Dim rng As Range
Dim ele As WebElement

' 
lastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


bot.Start "chrome", "URL HERE"
bot.Get "/"

For X = 2 To lastRow
   Set ele = bot.FindElementById("calendarId").AsSelect
   ele.SelectByValue "30"
' Above threw an runt time error 59

bot.FindElementById("calendarId").Click
' this opens up the calender's pop up 

bot.Wait 500

Also, tRied the below combinations: 


' cScript = "document.getElementsByClass('a-cal-days').value='29'"

' bot.ExecuteScript cScript


' For Each ele In bot.FindElementsByXPath("//select[@class='a-cal-select-day[]']")

' ele.AsSelect = Sheet1.Cells(X, 4)

' bot.FindElementById("calendarInputId").Value ("10/29/2019")

' bot.FindElementByXPath("(//[@class='a-cal-d'])").Text Sheet1.Cells(X, 5)

' bot.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='calendarId']/div[1]/select[2])).setAttribute('value', '24')

' //*[@id="calendarId"]/div[1]/select[1] ' Month

' //*[@id='calendarId']/div[1]/select[2] ' day select

' //*[@id="calendarId"]/div[1]/select[2]
```

Cells Values; needing to match calendar day and month: See attached image!
HTML BELOW:

```html
<td>
  <div id="calendarId" data-a-cal-attributes="{&quot;minDate&quot;:{&quot;month&quot;:10,&quot;year&quot;:2019,&quot;day&quot;:23},&quot;maxDate&quot;:{&quot;month&quot;:10,&quot;year&quot;:2020,&quot;day&quot;:24},&quot;selectedDate&quot;:{&quot;month&quot;:10,&quot;year&quot;:2019,&quot;day&quot;:24}}"
    data-a-cal-input="true" class="a-cal-calendar-container a-cal-static">
    <div class="a-cal-dropdown-container">
      <select data-action="a-cal-dropdown-select" class="a-cal-select-month a-declarative">
        <option value="">Month</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
      </select>
      <select data-action="a-cal-dropdown-select" class="a-cal-select-day a-declarative">
        <option value="">Day</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="13">13</option>
        <option value="14">14</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
        <option value="16">16</option>
        <option value="17">17</option>
        <option value="18">18</option>
        <option value="19">19</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="21">21</option>
        <option value="22">22</option>
        <option value="23">23</option>
        <option value="24">24</option>
        <option value="25">25</option>
        <option value="26">26</option>
        <option value="27">27</option>
        <option value="28">28</option>
        <option value="29">29</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="31">31</option>
      </select>
      <select data-action="a-cal-dropdown-select" class="a-cal-select-year a-declarative">
        <option value="">Year</option>
        <option value="1900">1900</option>
        <option value="1901">1901</option>
        <option value="1902">1902</option>
        <option value="1903">1903</option>
        <option value="1904">1904</option>
        <option value="1905">1905</option>
        <option value="1906">1906</option>
        <option value="1907">1907</option>
        <option value="1908">1908</option>
        <option value="1909">1909</option>
        <option value="1910">1910</option>
        <option value="1911">1911</option>
        <option value="1912">1912</option>
        <option value="1913">1913</option>
        <option value="1914">1914</option>
        <option value="1915">1915</option>
        <option value="1916">1916</option>
        <option value="1917">1917</option>
        <option value="1918">1918</option>
        <option value="1919">1919</option>
        <option value="1920">1920</option>
        <option value="1921">1921</option>
        <option value="1922">1922</option>
        <option value="1923">1923</option>
        <option value="1924">1924</option>
        <option value="1925">1925</option>
        <option value="1926">1926</option>
        <option value="1927">1927</option>
        <option value="1928">1928</option>
        <option value="1929">1929</option>
        <option value="1930">1930</option>
        <option value="1931">1931</option>
        <option value="1932">1932</option>
        <option value="1933">1933</option>
        <option value="1934">1934</option>
        <option value="1935">1935</option>
        <option value="1936">1936</option>
        <option value="1937">1937</option>
        <option value="1938">1938</option>
        <option value="1939">1939</option>
        <option value="1940">1940</option>
        <option value="1941">1941</option>
        <option value="1942">1942</option>
        <option value="1943">1943</option>
        <option value="1944">1944</option>
        <option value="1945">1945</option>
        <option value="1946">1946</option>
        <option value="1947">1947</option>
        <option value="1948">1948</option>
        <option value="1949">1949</option>
        <option value="1950">1950</option>
        <option value="1951">1951</option>
        <option value="1952">1952</option>
        <option value="1953">1953</option>
        <option value="1954">1954</option>
        <option value="1955">1955</option>
        <option value="1956">1956</option>
        <option value="1957">1957</option>
        <option value="1958">1958</option>
        <option value="1959">1959</option>
        <option value="1960">1960</option>
        <option value="1961">1961</option>
        <option value="1962">1962</option>
        <option value="1963">1963</option>
        <option value="1964">1964</option>
        <option value="1965">1965</option>
        <option value="1966">1966</option>
        <option value="1967">1967</option>
        <option value="1968">1968</option>
        <option value="1969">1969</option>
        <option value="1970">1970</option>
        <option value="1971">1971</option>
        <option value="1972">1972</option>
        <option value="1973">1973</option>
        <option value="1974">1974</option>
        <option value="1975">1975</option>
        <option value="1976">1976</option>
        <option value="1977">1977</option>
        <option value="1978">1978</option>
        <option value="1979">1979</option>
        <option value="1980">1980</option>
        <option value="1981">1981</option>
        <option value="1982">1982</option>
        <option value="1983">1983</option>
        <option value="1984">1984</option>
        <option value="1985">1985</option>
        <option value="1986">1986</option>
        <option value="1987">1987</option>
        <option value="1988">1988</option>
        <option value="1989">1989</option>
        <option value="1990">1990</option>
        <option value="1991">1991</option>
        <option value="1992">1992</option>
        <option value="1993">1993</option>
        <option value="1994">1994</option>
        <option value="1995">1995</option>
        <option value="1996">1996</option>
        <option value="1997">1997</option>
        <option value="1998">1998</option>
        <option value="1999">1999</option>
        <option value="2000">2000</option>
        <option value="2001">2001</option>
        <option value="2002">2002</option>
        <option value="2003">2003</option>
        <option value="2004">2004</option>
        <option value="2005">2005</option>
        <option value="2006">2006</option>
        <option value="2007">2007</option>
        <option value="2008">2008</option>
        <option value="2009">2009</option>
        <option value="2010">2010</option>
        <option value="2011">2011</option>
        <option value="2012">2012</option>
        <option value="2013">2013</option>
        <option value="2014">2014</option>
        <option value="2015">2015</option>
        <option value="2016">2016</option>
        <option value="2017">2017</option>
        <option value="2018">2018</option>
        <option value="2019">2019</option>
        <option value="2020">2020</option>
        <option value="2021">2021</option>
        <option value="2022">2022</option>
        <option value="2023">2023</option>
        <option value="2024">2024</option>
        <option value="2025">2025</option>
        <option value="2026">2026</option>
        <option value="2027">2027</option>
        <option value="2028">2028</option>
        <option value="2029">2029</option>
        <option value="2030">2030</option>
        <option value="2031">2031</option>
        <option value="2032">2032</option>
        <option value="2033">2033</option>
        <option value="2034">2034</option>
        <option value="2035">2035</option>
        <option value="2036">2036</option>
        <option value="2037">2037</option>
        <option value="2038">2038</option>
        <option value="2039">2039</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="a-cal-date-range-group a-cal-date-range-group-vertical">
      <div class="a-cal-date-range-wrapper">
        <div class="a-input-text-addon-group-wrapper">
          <div class="a-input-text-addon-group a-width-medium"><span class="a-input-text-addon"><i class="a-icon a-icon-calendar"></i></span><input type="text" maxlength="10" data-action="a-cal-input" data-input="start" class="a-input-text a-cal-input a-declarative" id="calendarInputId" /></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that it is the `select` element which serves as the base. Also, I don't think you can grab the window handle of pop-up and use that to switch to pop-up but you could try `bot.SwitchToNextWindow`. You return to original with `bot.SwitchToDefaultContent`.

E.g.

```
bot.SwitchToNextWindow

Dim monthSel As Object, daySel As Object

Set monthSel = bot.FindElementByCss(".a-cal-select-month").AsSelect
Set daySel = bot.FindElementByCss(".a-cal-select-day").AsSelect
Set yearSel = bot.FindElementByCss(".a-cal-select-year").AsSelect
```

Then I would expect you to be able to leverage SelectBy methods e.g.

```
                            ''<== assuming cell contains value 1
monthSel.SelectByText "10"   'or  monthSel.SelectByText ActiveSheet.Cells(2,1).value

daySel.SelectByValue "29"   
yearSel.SelectByValue 2019   'different ways of doing same thing shown
```

Be careful with your current lastRow calculation and looping method. The AsSelect can be done outside any loops as you don't need to set new references (at least I don't think so); you only want to alter the currently selected value in the dropdowns.

Comment: Thanks; so I tried the below code: 'Sub googStart()
Dim bot As New WebDriver
Dim rng As Range
Dim ele As WebElement
Dim monthSel As Object
Dim daySel As Object
lastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For X = 2 To lastRow

Comment: 'Set monthSel = bot.FindElementByCss(".a-cal-select-month").AsSelect
Set daySel = bot.FindElementByCss(".a-cal-select-day").AsSelect
Set yearSel = bot.FindElementByCss(".a-cal-select-year").AsSelect
bot.FindElementById("calendarInputId").Click
monthSel.SelectByValue "10" ' Sheet1.Cells(X, 5).Value
daySel.SelectByValue "31" 'Sheet1.Cells(X, 6).Value
yearSel.SelectByValue 2019
bot.Wait 500'

Comment: but.. it gave me a run time error '11' ElementNotVisibleError; element not intractable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated.

Comment: Should also note- the colander box is not a drop down, it’s a pop up box

Comment: You need to switch to that window. Normal way (at least in other languages is https://stackoverflow.com/a/29052586/6241235)  but could try as shown in my edit to answer above if vba doesn't implement the gethandles.