# Closing Modal using Selenium in Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, modal-dialog

I've been trying to close a modal for some time now and somehow nothing works.

The last thing I tried was executing a JS script. It works if I execute it in the browser console but not with selenium.

I used:

`driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('btnChiudi').click()`

to close:

```
        <div id="ctl00_mainCopy_upMsgFePa">
                <div tabindex="-1" id="Modal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">
                                    <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"><input type="image" name="ctl00$mainCopy$CustomImageButton1" id="ctl00_mainCopy_CustomImageButton1" disabled="disabled" src="" style="border-width:0px;"></span>
                                    <span id="ctl00_mainCopy_Label1">Avviso</span></h5><button type="button" class="btn--close close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" id="btnCloseX" onclick="$get('btnChiudi').click()">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button></div><div class="modal-body">
                                <center>
                                    <span id="ctl00_mainCopy_msgAttenzioneFePa" style="display:inline-block;border-width:0px;border-style:None;font-size:11pt;width:97%;text-align: left">TEXT<ul id="ctl00_mainCopy_blListConvInComp" style="text-align: left; padding-left: 25px;"><li>TEXT</li></ul>TEXT</span><table id="ctl00_mainCopy_TblElencoConvenzioniSenzaSceltaFePa" width="100%">
                                    <tbody><tr>
                                        <td>&nbsp; </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                             <ul id="ctl00_mainCopy_blListConvInComp" style="text-align: left; padding-left: 25px;">
                                                  <li>SSP00703052</li>
                                             </ul>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </tbody></table>
                                </center>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <input type="submit" name="ctl00$mainCopy$btnChiudi" value="Chiudi" id="btnChiudi" class="btn btn--secondary" data-dismiss="modal">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wz9pE.jpg)

Comment: I got it to work with this method:
[Link to other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676036/python-webdriver-to-handle-pop-up-browser-windows-which-is-not-an-alert)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try with below xpath with Explicit waits like below  :

**XPATH  :**

```
//input[@id='btnChiudi']/..
```

**code :**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='btnChiudi']/.."))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: I've already tried this and it doesn't work. I get a `TimeoutException`

Comment: Can you try this instead `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='btnChiudi']/..").click()` - in this case we will have proper exception, Explicit wait always throws timeout exception.

Comment: Now I get a `NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element` error

Comment: okay I think, it's either in iframe or not in Selenium view port. Where is this element seen in the UI ? also can you check for iframes  ?

Comment: It's in the middle of the screen with darkened background...looks like a standard modal... and I could't find any iframe tag on the site

Comment: Is it possible to share the page URL ?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wz9pE.jpg here you can see how it looks, I could share the URL but it won't help because you have to be logged in to get to this page

Comment: or you can share the page resource as well. do this `print(driver.page_source)`

Comment: and is that the blue color cross mark that you wanna click ?

Comment: Chiudi means close, so that's a close button too and it doesn't really matter which one because the one with the x executes a JS that clicks the 'Chiudi' button

Comment: Alright, can you share the page resource as well ?

Comment: It's too long to post

Comment: I shared the code of the modal in my main question, the x button is on line 8 and the ''chiudi' on line 26

Answer (score 0):

It works by getting the windows and switching between them because bootstrap doesn't actually generate real popups but uses different windows to show modals and you can switch between them using this code: [Python webdriver to handle pop up browser windows which is not an alert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676036/python-webdriver-to-handle-pop-up-browser-windows-which-is-not-an-alert)